# QT: Custom image streaming widget enters infinite recursion

Tags: c++, qt

I have a source of images that I wish to feed one after the other and show to the user.
For that end I created a QWidget application and tried to create a custom widget whose job is simply to paint the images it receives (code attached at the end of the post).
I use it by adding a widget in the Designer and promoting it to the proper class.
When running said widget the program crashes with the message "QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected".
Any Ideas what might cause it?

please note that I don't have any custom code in the project except for a few button clicking events that changes the active StackedWidget, everything else is strictly generated by the designer itself.

Widget header:

```
#ifndef IMSTREAMWIDGET_H
#define IMSTREAMWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

class ImStreamWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ImStreamWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent){}
    virtual ~ImStreamWidget(){}
    void updateImage(cv::Mat image);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);

private:
    QImage *_image;
};

#endif // IMSTREAMWIDGET_H
```

Widget source:
    #include "imstreamwidget.h"

```
void ImStreamWidget::updateImage(cv::Mat image){

cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);

// _image is created according to video dimensions
if (_image)
{
    delete _image;
}
_image = new QImage(image.size().width, image.size().height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

// Copy cv::Mat to QImage
memcpy(_image->scanLine(0), (unsigned char*)image.data, _image->width() * _image->height() * image.channels());

// Resize the window to fit video dimensions
resize(image.size().width, image.size().height);
}

void ImStreamWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    // When no image has been loaded, there's nothing to draw.
    if (_image){
        painter.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), *_image);
    }
    QWidget::paintEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Do you call `repaint()`? Don't, instead call `update()` method.
As a side note, you don't need to `new QImage...`, because it uses implicit COW data sharing. So you can pass QImages around as values, and Qt will take care of memory management for you.

Comment: The code you see above is all the custom code that I use.
Everything else is generated using the Designer.

Comment: The variable `_image` is not initialized in the constructor. So if `paintEvent` is called before `updateImage`, the `_image` pointer will contain an invalid reference.

Comment: @agold - that was the problem. thank you!